# BlackBerry: Dozens of net_rim_services_impl Threads when debugging

Tags: multithreading, debugging, blackberry

When debugging my application I see dozens of net_rim_services_impl. Is that normal behaviour or is my app causing that trouble.

Can some give me an explanation what is in net_rim_services_impl?

I use GPS/Geolocation with several LocationListeners and my app consists of a gui-thread and a background thread with a separate entry point that is auto-started. It is listening for push notifies within that thread.

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal behavior.

Here's a couple of links with people dealing with net_rim_services_impl errors.
But I don't think you are dealing with them. Aren't you?

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Application-net-rim-services-impl-14-is-not-responding-process/m-p/140453/highlight/true#M16090

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Process-net-rim-services-impl-14-queue-too-large-key-stylus/m-p/187664/highlight/true#M24680